# how to dynamically render and update chart.js line graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, chart.js

I am receiving a json formated data from the server in form like similiar to this:

```
{"id":"1","temp1":"22","temp2":"33","hum":"55", "date":"02-08-2020"}, 
{"id":"2","temp1":"33","temp2":"44","hum":"44", "date":"02-08-2020"}, 
{"id":"3","temp1":"12","temp2":"25","hum":"66", "date":"02-08-2020"}
```

But the thing is that it is one of few possible datasets. Received data can have any number of fields between "id" and "date", so I want to dynamically create and render my chart.js line Chart.

I've tried to mock server response and test my logic to see if it works. These are my global variables:

```
var data = [];
var jsonString = '[{"id":"1","temp1":"22","temp2":"33","hum":"55"},{"id":"2","temp1":"33","temp2":"44","hum":"44"},{"id":"3","temp1":"12","temp2":"25","hum":"66"}]';
var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

//chart.js config arrays
var graphColors = [
  '#0275d8',
  '#d9534f',
  '#5cb85c',
  '#f0ad4e',
  '#5bc0de'
];

var graphDatasets = [];
```

I have a function called init which gets called as soon as window loads:

```
window.onload=init();
```

In this function I extract and order my data to "data" array with key:value, so each recieved object's property from "myData" object with it's key gets mapped under that key in array so that I have something like this (although I am not sure if this is the best approach):

```
[{"id:[1,2,3]"},{"temp1:[22,33,12]"}, {"temp2:[33,44,25]"}.....]
```

In this init function I also prepare the graphDatasets array to be able to pass it to 'datasets' property for chart.js.

this is my init function:

```
function init() {
      var temp = [];
      myData.slice(-2).forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
          if (!temp[k]) data.push({ [k]: temp[k] = [] });
          temp[k].push(v);
      }));
      //Populate graphDatasets array
      var i = 0;
      for(var key in data) {
        if ((key !== "id") || (key !== "date") ) {
          graphDatasets.push({
            label: key,
            lineTension: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
            borderColor: graphColors[i],
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointBackgroundColor: graphColors[i],
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
            pointHoverRadius: 3,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            pointBorderWidth: 2,
            data: data[key]
          });
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
```

I try to check if the received keys are not 'id' or 'date' because I dont want to graph them, but the checking seems to not be working. What I am doing wrong, and how can I fix this issue and check for 'id' and 'date' field properly?

After that, I try to render chart, but with no success:

```
// Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartIndex");
var chartIndex = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: data[0].id,
    datasets: graphDatasets
  }
```

I believe I am trying to pass data to the chart all wrong.
But since I am new to javascript in general, I don't know how to properly handle this situation, in which I have JSON formatted data, that can change it's structure and, no matter how many data and what their key is, they need to be displayed on chart.

How to properly do this, and what fixes I need to do in my code and approach to achieve dynamic data charting based on json response?

I have prepared a fiddle here:
    https://jsfiddle.net/ph7ydonL/

Comment: use `for(var key in data[0])` .Add an index 0.

Comment: won't work, data[0] is just array of ID's

Answer (score 1):

I played a little with your example - I am not sure is that the result you are expecting to receive... In general you built the data object as list of maps where the key in the map is your dynamic attribute, I change it to the list of objects:

```js
/* var base_url = $('head base').attr('href'); */

//chart.js config arrays
var graphColors = [
  '#0275d8',
  '#d9534f',
  '#5cb85c',
  '#f0ad4e',
  '#5bc0de'
];

var graphDatasets = [];

const number_format = (a) => a;

// Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

var data = [];

window.onload = init();

function init() {
  var jsonString = '[{"id":"1","temp1":"22","temp2":"33","hum":"55"},{"id":"2","temp1":"33","temp2":"44","hum":"44"},{"id":"3","temp1":"12","temp2":"25","hum":"66"}]';
  var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var temp = [];
  myData.slice(-2).forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (!temp[k]) data.push({
      data: temp[k] = [],
      key: k
    });
    temp[k].push(v);
  }));
  //Populate graphDatasets array
  var i = 0;
  data.forEach((elem) => {
    if ((elem.key !== "id") && (elem.key !== "date")) {
      graphDatasets.push({
        label: elem.key,
        lineTension: 0.3,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
        borderColor: graphColors[i],
        pointRadius: 3,
        pointBackgroundColor: graphColors[i],
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
        pointHoverRadius: 3,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
        data: elem.data
      });
      i++;
    }
  })
}

//console.log(data[0]);
//console.log(graphDatasets);

// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartIndex");
var chartIndex = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: data[0].id,
    datasets: graphDatasets
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 25,
        top: 25,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          padding: 10,
          // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '$' + number_format(value);
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [2],
          zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      titleMarginBottom: 10,
      titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
      titleFontSize: 14,
      borderColor: '#dddfeb',
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
      caretPadding: 10,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
          var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
          return datasetLabel + ': $' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var updateChart = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: base_url + '//',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {

      var obj = response.parse();
      var i = 0;

      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, index) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          data.key.push(obj[key]);
          chartIndex.data.labels.push(obj.date);
          chartIndex.data.datasets[i].data.push(data.key);
          i++;
        }
      });
      // re-render the chart
      myChart.update();
    }
  });
};

// get new data every 3 seconds
//setInterval(updateChart, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartIndex" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```